# slurm python multiprocessing exceed memory limit

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, multiprocessing, slurm

My multiprocessing code in python works on my computer perfectly. But when I use slurm, I get an `Exceed job` memory error. I can not figure out how to solve this problem.  In [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421171/slurm-exceeded-job-memory-limit-with-python-multiprocessing) @jaap suggests using cgroups accounting, but I do not understand how to implement it. Also i haven't authorize to change it. Can anyone suggest a solution? Below you can see my slurm code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -p mid1
#SBATCH -A rrrr
#SBATCH -J python_auvergne
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -c 16
#SBATCH --time=04-00:00:00

#export PATH=$/truba/home/rulug/anaconda3/bin/:$PATH


module load centos7.3/comp/gcc/7

python3 V1.py


exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify the memory requirement in the submission script, so you get the default value, which might be very low.

Add `#SBATCH --mem=4GB` or more to request more memory.

But beware that for a Python multiprocessing job, you need to specify `-c 16` rather that `-n 16` because the later will potentially allocate jobs on distinct nodes (servers), which the `multiprocessing` module is not able to handle, while the former will make sure all reserved cores are on the same node.

Comment: Firstly thanks for answer. I tried --mem=90GB which is maximum values. at the beginning i thought it worked but after a point it gave me same error. Also used -c 16 instead of -n 16 nothing changed. Still i have same problem.

Comment: What figures are you seing in the memory-related (*RSS, *VM) columns of `sacct -j <your job id>` ?

Comment: There are no column related to RSS and VM in sacct results,  maybe because of i used sbatch intead of srun. I will run it again using srun then i will give the result.

Comment: MaxRSS MaxRSSTask     AveRSS  MaxVMSize  AveVMSize AveDiskWrite MaxDiskWrite 
50013996K          0  49957916K 284507664K 284443280K     2589.83M     2589.83M 

@damienfrancois this is result

Comment: It looks like you used 50GB, not 90GB. Maybe check that no other system than Slurm is limiting memory?

Comment: I will check it , if find something i will tell you. Thanks again

Comment: i checked and found nothing. After talked to you, realized that in every step MaxRSS increases after a point it exceed max limit. However in my local computer MaxRss remain same. still couldn't find the solution. Here[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421171/slurm-exceeded-job-memory-limit-with-python-multiprocessing] suggest use cgroup accounting but i am not authorized to change slurm.conf

Comment: The problem fixed when they changed linux accounting to cgroups. I did not realize what is difference but at least problem solved. Thanks everyone